# Spring @Scheduled issue with Scheduling

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

I am have bean I want to function in spring I want run only once a day at midnight. for test it put date into queue when it runs and dies.

I am having issue  making it work as it should.

```
 @Scheduled(cron = "1 0 * * * *")
```

when I put it this way, the the function is executed every hour instead of every midnight

"Tue Mar 24 12:00:02 PDT 2015": "Reset",
"Tue Mar 24 13:00:02 PDT 2015": "Reset"

Here is my confs as well

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.bla" />

   <mvc:annotation-driven />

   <task:annotation-driven executor="taskExecutor" 
 scheduler="taskScheduler"/>

  <task:scheduler id="taskScheduler" pool-size="1" />


  <bean id="taskExecutor"


 class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor" 
 destroy-method="shutdown">

    <property name="corePoolSize" value="100" />

    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="150" />

    <property name="WaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown" value="false" />

  </bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring uses quartz scheduler with a bit different syntax than cron (look here http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger) 
It starts from seconds not minutes so your expression shoudl be:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "1 0 0 * * ?")
```